# AAPT2 error: in Android Studio 3.1.3

Tags: android

**AAPT2 error: check logs for details in Android Studio 3.1.3**

Error: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.android.builder.internal.aapt.v2.Aapt2Exception: AAPT2 error: check logs for details

Comment: try invalidate cache andn restart option form menu

Comment: comment worked for me from menu.
File > Invalidate Caches / Restart

Answer (score 1):

I solved this issue by follow this process

Click on Gradle in Right side  *Gradle -> Project Name -> App -> Tasks -> build -> assembleDebug*

By clicking on *assebleDebug* will show you the line where is the problem. In my case, I have an issue in my XML file

Answer (score 0):

For now, solution is adding **gradle.properties** this code

```
android.enableAapt2=false
```